# A tool for collecting system information?

Tags: windows, software-rec, system-info

I am looking for a tool that can produce a report (xml/xslt, html, pdf, etc..) of the system and all of its hardware components such as processor, speed, memory, disks, network, etc..

Any idea if such a tool exists? The more information it gives the better.

Comment: Is this software for a particular operating system?

Comment: This is definitely dependent on what OS you're using. Please specify

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/182695/best-free-way-to-dump-system-hardware-information-to-a-txt-xml-file-in-win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command is built-in to Windows:

```
systeminfo
```

It doesn't give much, but it does address your request for processor, memory, and network.

Disks can be easily queried for all sorts of info from the following built-in Windows command:

```
fsutil
```

You'll want to try `fsutil` that with a `/?` switch to see some of the options available. More specific drive information is available within `diskpart`, also a built-in command.

For "speed", I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Perhaps you're looking for a benchmark utility? If so, try SiSoft Sandra. The free version [is available here](http://www.sisoftware.net/?d=&f=home&l=en&a=) (Go to download & buy at the top).

Answer (score 2):

[Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) by Piriform is another good one and can [save reports in XML or text file formats as well as post to the web](http://www.piriform.com/docs/speccy/using-speccy).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the exporting to a report part but you can have a look at the features.

There is:

- [Lavalys AIDA64 (Formerly Everest)](http://www.aida64.com/product/aida64-extreme-edition/overview)
- [SIW | System Information Tool](http://www.gtopala.com/)

Comment: SIW is awesome - it can generate HTML reports manually or by being run with a certain command line, so you could even get the reports automatically with a script.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you need:

Faronics - System Profiler
  http://www.faronics.com/en/Products/SystemProfiler.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) produces an HTML report.

*The Belarc Advisor builds a detailed profile of your installed software and hardware, missing Microsoft hotfixes, anti-virus status, CIS (Center for Internet Security) benchmarks, and displays the results in your Web browser. All of your PC profile information is kept private on your PC and is not sent to any web server.*

Answer (score 0):

[Astra32](http://www.astra32.com/) is another option.

Comment: Please expand this link. Link only answers may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[Sandra](http://www.sisoftware.net) by SiSoftware for Windows. It'll give you info on CPU, cores, chipset, memory, peripherals, video and more.

Answer (score 0):

[PC-Wizard](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/pc-wizard.html) is a great option for Windows and totally free. By the same source of an all-time favorite [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), which is excellent, free and fast for CPU and memory information. You can run both programs with and without installing them. Makes them low-impact and good for USB keys.