# Which kind of USB connectors does my computer have?

Tags: usb

How can I find out which kind of USB (USB-1, USB-2 or USB-3) connectors my computer has?

EDIT:
Running Windows XP and Windows 7 on my computers.

Comment: What make and model of computer do you have? Unless your computer is fairly old or very new, you probably have USB-2 connectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

USB 3 is visibly different (taller) from previous generations, so it is usually easy to view them and work out whether you've got USB 3 connectors (they're also often blue).

You can't visually separate USB 1 and USB 2, however when you consult your operating system you'll see that the USB controller is OHCI, UHCI (both USB 1), EHCI (USB 2) or xHCI (USB 3). Exactly how you do that will depend on the operating system - with Windows XP and later check Device Manager, for Linux and BSD look at the output of `dmesg`.

---

**Edit**

> The device manager only tells me that I have a Standard Enhanced PCI to USB host Controller, USB Root Hub... Clicking on them does not reveal anything about USB1 or USB2.

Then that's EHCI - USB 2.

Comment: The device manager only tells me that I have a Standard Enhanced PCI to USB host Controller, USB Root Hub... Clicking on them does not reveal anything about USB1 or USB2.

Comment: @AnnaR - Try one of these programs that show detailed system information... http://superuser.com/questions/274306/a-tool-for-collecting-system-information